# Index value for - VBA Excel macro that changes value of cell and runs the model

Tags: excel, vba, indexing

I created a macro that changes value in cell named "option". Once the value is changes results in the model change to reflect that.

For example:

```
a) Option 1: best case scenario sales -> Cell "option" input 1 
b) Option 2: worst case scenario sales -> Cell "option" input 2
c) etc
```

The macro then copies the results from the model into a new table.
So for examples it copies the results of the model from cell named "costs" (which is dynamic cell that depends on what model spits out) to a new cell called "costs_1", which will be static.
Example of code below.

The macro works really well, however if I would want to enter 100 options then the code would be very long.

Can somebody help with how to create a general reference within the code e.g. Dim i As Integer i = i + 1, which would run until 100? that would change the cells names e.g. costs_i then it goes, costs_1, costs_2 costs_3 ... etc.

Would very much appreciate your help.

Best regards
Jan

```
Sub RunModel()
' RunModel Macro
....
'Choose Option 1 
Range("option").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

'Copy costs when option 1 is selected to a new cell
[costs].Select
Selection.Copy
[costs_1].Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Copy number of customers when option 1 is selected to a new cell
[customers].Select
Selection.Copy
[customers_1].Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

....
etc
....

'Choose Option 2
Range("option").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "2"

'Copy costs when option 2 is selected to a new cell
[costs].Select
Selection.Copy
[costs_2].Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Copy number of customers when option 2 is selected to a new cell
[customers].Select
Selection.Copy
[customers_2].Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

....
etc
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub RunModel()
    dim i as long
    for i = 1 to 100 'Change this to whatever you need it to be
        'No need to select and activate cells or use the clipboard, just copy the values
        range("option").FormulaR1C1 = i
        range("costs_" & i).value = range("costs").value
        range("customers_" & i).value = range("customers").value
        'Do some more stuff
    next i
    'Do some more stuff
end sub
```